# Prove the diagonals of rhumbus are perpendicular and angles bisector

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, triangles

thank you for your time.

There are many aways to approach this problem, but I tried to do it the long way. I am not quite good at math proofs, which makes me tend to mess the logic up. It would be great if someone verify my proof on this one :)

Let $ABCD$ a rhumbus, then $AB=BC=CD=DA$;

$\triangle ABD$ is isosceles with height $OD$ and base $AC$ **(which is one of the diagonals of the rhumbus)**, therefore $<DAC=<DCA$;

Since $OD$ is the height of $\triangle ADC$, $<DOA = <DOC = 90º$;

$\triangle ABD$ is isosceles with base $BD$ **(which one of the diagonal of the rhumbus)**. Notice that $BD$ intersects $AC$ such that $<AOB$, & $<DOC$, $<COB$ & $<DOA$ are vertically opposite angles, Then $<AOB = <DOC = <DOA=<COB=90º$;

Therefore the diagonals of a rhumbus bisect the angles (because the heights $\in$ the diagonals) and are perpendiculat to the other

Comment: Rhombus. I googled Rhumbus & got nothing but Rhombus.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

Using simple vectors/complex number approach, which is just one step away compared to the Euclidean approach...it calculates easier due to equality all boundary vector lengths.

The rhombus is a particular case of a parallelogram.

[image]

$$ e^{i \theta}= \cos {\theta}+ i \sin {\theta} = c+ i\; s = \vec{ BC} = \vec {AD}$$

*Perpendicularity/Orthogonality*

of diagonals can be verified:

$$ ( ( c+ i s +1) \cdot ( (c +i s -1)= c^2-1+s^2 =0 $$

*Arguments of Vectors*

$$ \arg( 2 +  e^{i \theta}) =  \theta$$

$$ \arg( 1 +  e^{i \theta} )=  \theta + \theta =2 \theta $$

( External angle sum equals sum of two internal angles)

The resultant vector is hence a bisector also.

Comment: +1. After obtaining  $BD\perp AC ,$  observe that $\triangle DAB$ is isosceles with $AB=AD$ so the perpendicular $AO$ from $A$ to $BD$ is also the bisector of $\angle BAD.$

Comment: Thank you. I left some blanks in the hints,  not to make a complete answer.